# How To Creat Pause , Stop and Resume Button In WIN APP When a File Is Copied?

Tags: file-copying

### How To Creat Pause And Stop and Resume Button In WIN APP When a File Is Copied ?

a Snapshot Of Design MyProject  :

http://www.uploadtak.com/images/f7636_Snapshot_20121207_14.jpg

a Snapshot Of Code MyProject  :

http://www.uploadtak.com/images/y564_Snapshot_20121207_14.jpg

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

```
            for (int i = 0; i <= inStream.Length; i++)
            {

                worker.ReportProgress(i);

                //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);

                fileStream.SetLength(inStream.Length);
                int bytesRead = -1;
                byte[] bytes = new byte[bufferSize];

                while (puase);

                if (cancel)
                {
                    offsetw = 0; fileStream.Flush();
                    return;

                }
                bytesRead = inStream.Read(bytes, offsetw, bufferSize);

                fileStream.Write(bytes, offsetw, bytesRead);
                offsetw *= 1024;

            }
```

The inner empty while loop, pause operation, you can toggle puase value in Pause Button